# Showing only a portion of uiimage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have created a UIImageview programmatically, and I am showing an image from a string which contains url of a picture

But I wish to show a part(a rectangle at center) of the original image.  How do I achieve this?

```
    NSString * urlString = @"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-  rEqVgkdnuxE/TWd6Fm6EWtI/AAAAAAAABSc/cWCehI51v_Y/s1600/red_rose_flower3.jpg"

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Comment: You can read more information in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035673/most-efficient-way-to-draw-part-of-an-image-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size :)

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:SIZEOFRECTANGLE];
[imageView setContentModeCenter];
```

Comment: This code has one problem on retina screen. Let I have a picture with image size 400px x 400px and want to see its center view in the frame of size 200pt x 200pt. System interprets your image as retina image of 800px x 800px and get its half to fill area of  200pt x 200pt = 400px x 400px. Thus, you'll the center of your initial image twice magnified  and effectively with twice worse quality.

Comment: In the code above you must add important line
*imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;*
Without it you'll still see the whole image out the bounds of UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

The very simple way to move big image inside *UIImageView* as follows.

Let we have the image of size (imgX, imgY) in pixels and we want to show its center in the frame of size (sizeX, sizeY) in points.
The solution is:

```
UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY)];
iView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NAME"];
CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(1/2-sizeX/imgX, 1/2-sizeY/imgY, 2*sizeX/imgX, 2*sizeY/imgY);
iView.layer.contentsRect = contentFrame;
```

Here *contentFrame* is normalized frame relative to real *UIImage* size.
It will be the original view of image without magnifications.